# Is there a point to use async/await on methods that return a value?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Just a question I'm curious about, can't quite find the answer.

In C# I have a call that retrieves an object then does something with that result.  What is the gain in making these async?

```cs
var result = await _repo.GetMyItem(itemId);

if(result.Category == 1) { // do something }
```

What's the benefit of `GetMyItem()` being async if the result is needed on the next line?

Comment: The benefit is that if  `GetMyItem` is IO bound or CPU bound and run on a separate thread that the current thread is not blocked while it waits for it to complete.  This can help to not freeze up the UI thread or create many blocked threads if this is say code on a web server.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328203/why-would-you-ever-await-a-method-and-then-immediately-interrogate-its-return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be so selfish - you're not the only one that exists :)

I joke, but that is the point. There are other things to be done! If that code is run synchronously, then the thread would be dormant - doing nothing - while it waits to get the data. That task might only take 100ms, but that's a lot of time in CPU time.

Using `async`/`await` allows the thread to go and work on some other code that might need to be run in your application while you're waiting for that task to complete, rather than just sitting around waiting and doing nothing.

It's described really well in a Microsoft article called [The Task asynchronous programming model in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/), especially the illustration it uses about making breakfast.

In ASP.NET it is especially important because there is a limited number of threads in the thread pool. So the more you can do with a single thread, the better.

Comment: That's what I thought might be the case, similar to js, but didn't see why it would need to, thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Right. It's exactly the same idea as in JavaScript. I was going to use JS as an example, but I wasn't sure if that would mean anything to you :)

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of the async/await pattern if that if the call to `GetMyItem` is long running (for example a call to a database or web service) then your calling thread will be freed up to do other thing whilst waiting for the call to complete.

Once the call completes the framework will schedule the continuation of your function of the next line (where the `if` is).